# UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down

Tags: swift, segue, uigesturerecognizer

I've set a GestureRecognizer for left/right but i'd also like to add a GestureRecognizer for down (but not up). When I apply the following, the swipe up works as expected on the device screen; however, UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down does nothing.

```
func addGesture() {
    // Gesture recognizers
    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
    leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
    rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

    let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
    downSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
}
```

Am I missing an identifier in the storyboard segue or is there something else I need to do for the device to recognize a down swipe?

Comment: code looks fine for direction down. How you tested for direction up? there is no code for it.

Comment: Yes, direction up works fine 
`let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
    upSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)`

No compile errors but the logs also show no response for any down gestures when .down is implemented.

Comment: There is no issue in the code. It works as expected.

Comment: What would this have to do with segues?

Comment: It is a transition from one scene to another scene: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cjjop48ftxly80p/Screenshot%202018-09-20%2007.25.42.png?dl=0.
ViewController2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6damxvugf7da0cd/Screenshot%202018-09-20%2007.26.34.png?dl=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func addGesture() {
    // Gesture recognizers

    let directions: [UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction] = [.left, .right, .down]
    for direction in directions {
        let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.swipeAction(swipe:)))
        gesture.direction = direction
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

}

@objc func swipeAction(swipe:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if let swipeGesture = swipe as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
        switch swipeGesture.direction {


        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left:
            print("Swiped left")    
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController5") as! ViewController5
            vc.hero.modalAnimationType = .fade
            hero.replaceViewController(with: vc)

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right:
            print("Swiped right")
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            vc.hero.modalAnimationType = .fade
            hero.replaceViewController(with: vc)

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.down:
            print("Swiped down")
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3
            vc.hero.modalAnimationType = .pull(direction: .down)
            hero.replaceViewController(with: vc)

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```